# ROBOTC - Programming Autonomous With Integrated Encoders

Tags: integrated, robotc

I have an X Drive that is coded in ROBOTC. My team and I have the integrated motor encoders already on the robot (for the autonomous period). However the code for them to run is incorrect. The current autonomous code is below. When I run it, it just goes forward forever and at different speeds.

I have looked at multiple tutorials, but none of them work. **Does anyone have the code to make the motors (393 Motors) go at a count of 720?**

---

```
#pragma config(I2C_Usage, I2C1, i2cSensors)
#pragma config(Sensor, I2C_1, sensorQuadEncoderOnI2CPort, AutoAssign)
#pragma config(Motor,  port2, FL, tmotorVex393_MC29, PIDControl, encoderPort, I2C_1)
#pragma config(Motor,  port3, BR, tmotorVex393_MC29, PIDControl, reversed, encoderPort, I2C_1)
#pragma config(Motor,  port8, BL, tmotorVex393_MC29, PIDControl, encoderPort, I2C_1)
#pragma config(Motor,  port9, FR, tmotorVex393_MC29, PIDControl, reversed, encoderPort, I2C_1)
//*!!Code automatically generated by 'ROBOTC' configuration wizard               !!*//

task main()
{
// Autonomous with Integrated Encoders
nMotorPIDSpeedCtrl[FL] = mtrSpeedReg;
nMotorPIDSpeedCtrl[FR] = mtrSpeedReg;
nMotorPIDSpeedCtrl[BL] = mtrSpeedReg;
nMotorPIDSpeedCtrl[BR] = mtrSpeedReg;

//Clears motor values
nMotorEncoder[FL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[FR] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BR] = 0;

//Forward
motor[FL] = 63;
motor[FR] = 63;
motor[BL] = 63;
motor[BR] = 63;
   while(nMotorEncoder[FL] < 720) {
}

//Clears motor values
nMotorEncoder[FL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[FR] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BR] = 0;

}
```

Comment: Could the encoder values be decreasing instead of increasing? Try changing your `while` condition to `nMotorEncoder[FL] > -720`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly stop the motors (not just zero out the encoders) after the while loop. Otherwise the robot doesn't know to stop; it just knows that it passed the encoder target.

So this code should work for you:

```
//Clears motor values
nMotorEncoder[FL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[FR] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BR] = 0;

 motor[FL] = 63;
 motor[FR] = 63;
 motor[BL] = 63;
 motor[BR] = 63;
//Forward
while(nMotorEncoder[FL] < 720) {
}
//stops motors
motor[FL] = 0;
motor[FR] = 0;
motor[BL] = 0;
motor[BR] = 0;
//Clears motor encoder values
nMotorEncoder[FL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[FR] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BL] = 0;
nMotorEncoder[BR] = 0;
```